# Do functional language compilers optimize a "filter, then map" operation on lists into a single pass?

Tags: functional-programming, compiler-optimization

I mostly use TypeScript during my work day and when applying functional patterns I oftentimes see a pattern like:

```js
const someArray = anotherArray.filter(filterFn).map(transformFn)
```

This code will filter through all of `anotherArray`'s items and then go over the filtered list (which may be identical if no items are filtered) again and map things. In other words, we iterate over the array twice.

This behavior could be achieved with a "single pass" over the array with a `reduce`:

```js
const someArray = anotherArray.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (filterFn(item) === false) {
    return acc;
  }
  acc.push(item);
  return acc;
}, [])
```

I was wondering if such optimization is something the transpiler (in the TS world) knows to do automatically and whether such optimizations are automatically done in more "functional-first" languages such as Clojure or Haskell. For example, I know that functional languages usually do optimizations with tail recursion, so I was wondering also about the "filter then map" case. Is this something that compilers actually do?

Comment: The transformation is not necessarily equivalent in the presence of side effects.

Comment: This depends on purity and lazyness. Layzness gives you more efficiency for free with regard to `map`/`reduce`, but to be lazy and additoinally conduct compiler based loop fusion purity is a requirement. A language that only supplies lazy data structures but isn't pure like Clojure needs transducers or other means to allow manual loop fusion.

Comment: +1 I had been wondering the same question from time to time. Also, do any compilers utilize the potential parallelism in such pure streams? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you usually shouldn't obsess about getting everything into a single pass. On small containers there is not that much difference between running a single-operation loop twice and running a dual-operation loop once. Aim to write code that's easily understandable. One for loop might be more readable than two, but a reduce is not more readable than a filter then map.

What the compiler does depends on your "container." When your loop is big enough to care about execution time, it's usually also big enough to care about memory consumption. So filtering then mapping on something like an [observable](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable) works on one element at a time, all the way through the pipeline, before processing the next element. This means you only need memory for one element, even though your observable could be infinite.

Comment: +1 for not obsessing on overhead efficiency over added simplicity. With that said, libraries, if not compilers nowadays, do cater such details and edge cases so that if one really needs to avoid the overhead, it is provided out of the box in the library. :) Stream operations may not mot be inefficient for most cases but there are applications where there are many 100s of business rules, and their processing accumulates. In that case, it would be nice to just be concerned about simple stream operations and let the library / compiler worry about those inefficiencies.